# Cargo remote deployment Glassfish 4.1 Fails GlassFish uses 100% CPU

Tags: cargo, glassfish-4.1

I have the following Problem with GlassFih 4.1 and Cargo.

I try to deploy an ear on a remote GlassFish 4.1 Server. Without success... 
Maven command: mvn cargo:redeploy
The Glassfish Server takes 100% of the CPU and that's it. The Maven process remains blocked... I have tried on a remote ubuntu and on a remote windows server.

On the same remote server with Glassfish 3.1.2.2 the remote deployment works perfectly.

Did anybody hava the same issue, and did find a solution?

I guess that the following cargo config is ok, since it works with GF 3.1.2.2 (with deployment-client version 3.1.2.2 and containerId to glassfish3x).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
              <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.4.10</version>

              <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>glassfish-deploy</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                         </goals>
                     </execution>
               </executions>

                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                            <log>target/cargo.log</log>
                            <logLevel>debug</logLevel>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>runtime</type>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.hostname>servername</cargo.hostname>
                                <cargo.rmi.port>4848</cargo.rmi.port>
                                <cargo.remote.port>8080</cargo.remote.port>                           <cargo.glassfish.domain.name>domain1</cargo.glassfish.domain.name>
                                <cargo.runtime.args>force=true</cargo.runtime.args>
                                <cargo.protocol>https</cargo.protocol>
                                <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                                <cargo.remote.password>admin</cargo.remote.password>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>

                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <location>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</location>
                                <properties>
                                    <name>${project.groupId}-${project.artifactId}-autodeploy</name>
                                </properties>
                                <type>ear</type>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>

                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.deployment</groupId>
                            <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
                            <version>4.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```